# Jupyter notebook can't find my ssl certfile, unless I run as sudo

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have configured jupyter notebook to run as a server.

I have configured `jupyter_notebook_config.py` like so:

```
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/absolute/path/to/my/certificate/fullchain.pem'
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = u'/absolute/path/to/my/certificate/privkey.pem'
```

If I run `jupyter notebook`, it returns:

```
    'certfile "%s" does not exist' % self.ssl_options["certfile"]
ValueError: certfile "/absolute/path/to/my/certificate/fullchain.pem" does not exist
```

The file actually does exists, at that location.

If I run `sudo jupyter notebook` everything works. 
However, I would rather not run this as sudo. What should I do?

Comment: What are the permission settings of the file and the directories on its path

Comment: They're all `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root`. Can I simply change the permission on these files?